# Calculate the flux of $x^3i+y^3j+z^3k$.

Tags: calculus

Calculate the flux of $x^3i+y^3j+z^3k$ on $S^2$, clearly I want to do $$\int_{\mathbb B^3(0)} 3x^2+3y^2+3z^2 dV$$ which is $$\iiint_{[0,2]^3}  3 \rho^4 \sin \phi d \rho d \phi d \theta$$ by change of variable. Am I right? Are there quicker ways to do this?

Comment: What is $S^2$? A sphere of radius $2$? Also what is $\mathbb{B}^3(0)$?

Comment: $S^2$ is standard notation for the two dimensional unit sphere (in $\mathbb{R}^3$).

Comment: $S^2 = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x^2 + y^2 +z^2 = 1\}.$ That's what I meant by "unit" -- the radius is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let ${\bf v}:=(x^3,y^3,z^3)$ be a flow field. Then by Gauss' divergence theorem
$$\int_{S^2}{\bf v}\cdot{\bf n}\>{\rm d}\omega=\int_B{\rm div}({\bf v})\>{\rm d}V=\int_0^1 3r^2\>4\pi r^2\>dr={12\pi\over5}\ .$$
Here we have partitioned the unit ball $B\subset{\mathbb R}^3$ into infinitesimal spherical shells of area $4\pi r^2$ and thickness $dr$.